# Does Qt support RSA encryption?

Tags: qt, encryption, rsa

Does Qt support rsa encryption,QSslkey seems doesn't work.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Qt supports RSA for SSL-connections.
There are no interfaces to use RSA keys directly.

You could take a look at the [Qt Cryptographic Architecture](https://invent.kde.org/libraries/qca) project.

Answer (score 2):

Qt is supporting RSA encryption. You have to indicate to QSslKey the correct algorithm used: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qssl.html#KeyAlgorithm-enum

Comment: It does not support RSA encryption for generic cases. E.g. you can't write sign/verify algorithms using Qt.

Answer (score 1):

If you want encrypt data without ssl dependencies then you can use my library [Qt-Secret](https://github.com/QuasarApp/Qt-Secret).
This library supports the qmake build system, which makes it very easy to connect to your project.

---

## For example:

## Build

- ```sh
  git clone 'https://github.com/QuasarApp/Qt-Secret.git'
  cd Qt-Secret
  git submodule update --init --recursive
  qmake -r 
  make -j8
  make test #(for testing)
  ```

## Include

### For qmake projects

- ```sh
  cd yourRepo
  git submodule add https://github.com/QuasarApp/Qt-Secret.git # add the repository of Qt-Secret into your repo like submodule
  git submodule update --init --update
  ```
- Include in your pro file the pri file of Qt-Secret library:

  ```sh
  include($$PWD/Qt-Secret/src/Qt-Secret.pri)
  ```
- Rebuild your project.

### For other build systems

- ```sh
  cd yourRepo
  git submodule add https://github.com/QuasarApp/Qt-Secret.git # add the repository of Qt-Secret into your repo like submodule
  git submodule update --init --update
  ```
- Add the rule to build Qt-Secret.
- Add `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS` for your build system .
- Rebuild your project.

---

## Usage

### RSA

#### Encryption and decryption of messages.

```cpp
#include <qrsaencryption.h>

    QByteArray pub, priv;
    QRSAEncryption e(QRSAEncryption::Rsa::RSA_2048);
    e.generatePairKey(pub, priv);
    QByteArray msg = "test message";

    auto encodeData = e.encode(msg, pub);
    auto decodeData = e.decode(encodeData, priv);
```

#### Signature and verification of the message signature.

```cpp
#include <qrsaencryption.h>

    QByteArray pub, priv;
    QRSAEncryption e;
    e.generatePairKey(pub, priv, QRSAEncryption::Rsa::RSA_128); // or other rsa size 

    QByteArray msg = "test message";

    auto signedMessage = e.signMessage(msg, priv);

    if (e.checkSignMessage(signedMessage, pub)) {
        // message signed success
    }
```

Comment: You ought to mention that this isn't part of Qt - it's a separate project (it seems to be GPLv3 only, whereas Qt is available under LGPL, if I remember correctly).

Comment: @tobySpeight You correctly noticed.
The library must be distributed under the LGPLv3 license.

In the [code](https://github.com/QuasarApp/Qt-Secret/blob/e1db81b71463caf38a562491ab5118216c1f66b6/src/Qt-RSA/qrsaencryption.cpp#L1), this can be seen.

GPLv3 license was chosen incorrectly, this problem has already been resolved.